# how to detect $result is a valid MySQL result resource in mysql_fetch_array($result)

Tags: php, mysql

It's written in PHP,

and sometimes when I restart mysql,

will report:

```
Debug Warning:line 24 - mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Is there any way to detect if $result is a valid MySQL result resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it'll be false if there's an error.

```
if ($result) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
} else {
    echo "MySQL error: " . mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do:

```
if ($result) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      // Do everything you need to in here
 }
```